# Can't Conditionally the style set of the span in react (css modules)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-modules

What I did.

```
  <span className="status">
    {isOnline}?{styles.online}: {styles.offline}
  </span>
```

Getting a data from JSON. Need to set a specific styling depending on the value

what i have in CSS module:

```
 .online {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.offline {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Mistake: instead of getting the class value, I am getting the classname

Answer (score 1):

```
<span className={`${styles.status} ${isOnline ? styles.online : styles.offline}`}>
...
</span>
```

Comment: Actually, I need to change the border color of the picture => and the picture is {props.avatar} and the style is {styles.avatar}

Comment: could you help, sir?

Comment: I will need more code to be able to help you, but glad to do it if you update your question with the relevant code

Answer (score 1):

```
<span className = {this.state.isOnline ? "status online" : "status offline"} ></span>
```

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isOnline: false
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({
        isOnline: !state.isOnline
    }))
  }
  
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div >
        < button onClick = {this.handleClick} > 
          Toggle Online 
        </button>  
        <br/>
        <span className = {this.state.isOnline ? "status online" : "status offline"} ></span> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}



ReactDOM.render( < Example / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.online {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.offline {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.status {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `classnames` library. It helps a lot with conditional class assigning:

```html
<span className={classnames(styles.status, {
  [styles.online]: isOnline,
  [styles.offline]: !isOnline,
})}>
</span>
```